# Give examples of a connected and a disconnected subset of the metric space (M, d)

Tags: real-analysis

Let (M, d) be a metric space.  Give the complete definition of a connected subset S of M.  Give examples of a connected and a disconnected subset of the metric space (M, d) where  $M=\{f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}|f \,is \,continuous\}$ and $d:M \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $d(f,g)=\int_a^b |f(x)-g(x)|\,dx$.  No finite sets allowed as examples.

$\textbf{Give the complete definition of a connected subset S of M.}$

A subset S of a metric space M is said to be connected if whenever U and V are disjoint open subsets of X, $$S \subseteq U \cup V \Rightarrow S \subseteq U or S \subseteq V$$

$\textbf{Give examples of a connected and a disconnected subset of the metric space (M, d)}$

I have thought about it but I haven't been able to find one.

Comment: How about a point, and two distinct points?

Comment: I am not allow to choice finite sets

Comment: Oops, didn't read that carefully enough, lol

Comment: How about constant functions having values $0$ through $1$, and then constant functions having value $0$ through $1$ except not $1/2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the space $M$ contains a homeomorphic copy of $\mathbb{R}$ via constant functions.  This gives easy examples of connected and non-connected infinite subsets of $M$.

A specific example of a connect set would be the set of constant functions, while a specific example of a non-connected would be the set of nonzero constant functions.